# Ruby regexp to turn snake_casing to PascalCasing?

Tags: ruby, regex, pascalcasing

I've created a web framework that uses the following function:

```
def to_class(text)
    text.capitalize
    text.gsub(/(_|-)/, '')
end
```

To turn directory names that are `snake_cased` or `hyphen-cased` into `PascalCased` class names for your project.

Problem is, the function only removed `_` and `-`, and doesn't capitalize the next letter. Using `.capitalize`, or `.upcase`, is there a way to achieve making your `snake/hyphen_/-cased` names into proper `PascalCased` class names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This splits the _-cased string into an array; capitalizes every member and glues the array back to a string:

```
def to_pascal_case(str)
  str.split(/-|_/).map(&:capitalize).join
end

p to_pascal_case("snake_cased") #=>"SnakeCased"
```

Your code does not work for several reasons:

- The resulting object of the capitalize method is discarded - you
  should do something like `text.capitalize!` or `text = text.capitalize`.
- But the `capitalize` method just `upcase`s the first letter of the string,
  not the first letter of every word.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice explanation, and short solution to the problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
gsub(/(?:^|[_-])([a-z])?/) { $1.upcase unless $1.nil? }
```

Comment: This is definitely a great short and simple solution.

Answer (score 2):

Rails has a similar method called [camelize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-camelize). It basically capitalizes every part of the string consisting of `[a-z0-9]` and removes everything else.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably golf it down to something smaller, but:

```
txt = 'foo-bar_baz'
txt.gsub(/(?:^|[-_])([a-z])/) { |m| m.upcase }.gsub(/[-_]/, '') # FooBarBaz
```